# Is there a way to create new var containing conditional value in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am a relatively new user to R and have been struggling with this issue.

Supposed I have the following df with 5 variables a:e

```
year <- c(1990:1994)
a <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
b <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
c <- c(0, 0, 5, 1, 0)
d <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
e <- c(0, 2, 0, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(year, a, b, c, d, e)
```

Then, how do I create a new variable "f", which contains "value > 0" according to "year".

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edited: the desired output is column f below

```
year a b c d e f
1990 1 0 0 0 0 1
1991 0 1 0 0 2 2
1992 0 0 5 0 0 1
1993 0 0 1 1 0 2
1994 0 2 0 0 1 2
```

Comment: Can you please show what your desired output for this sample input? I can't tell what you mean by *"value > 0" according to "year".* Should it be the count of values > 0? Or the column name of values > 0? (What happens if there are more than 1 value > 0?) Or something else?

Comment: Hi, yes a new column which contains the count of values > 0. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rowSums` to count how many values are `> 0`, excluding the first column.

```
df$f = rowSums(df[-1] > 0)

df
#   year a b c d e f
# 1 1990 1 0 0 0 0 1
# 2 1991 0 1 0 0 2 2
# 3 1992 0 0 5 0 0 1
# 4 1993 0 0 1 1 0 2
# 5 1994 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Looks so simple!

Comment: Suggest you review the Base R by-vector functions: rowSums, rowMeans, colSums, colMeans.  RStudio help: `?rowSums` will show you the info.

Comment: Hi @SteveM, thanks for your suggestion. I have another question re {colSums}, I understand that given the above example, the func will calculate the total values of specified columns. But is there a way to calculate the values of column a, c, and f from 1990-1992, and 1993-1994 respectively?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `apply` with `sum`

```
df$f <- apply(df[-1] > 0, 1, sum)
```